# HttpPost on various Controls

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

i am just learning ASP.NET-MVC with Razor, it all works quite well, i like it but i stumpled upon a problem, which is a result, as i think, of my lack of good old HTML Knowledge:

In good old ASP.NET, everything did Postbacks, if you added `runat="server"`. But in Razor the only way to do a Post-Event is, as i assume, a submit-button in a form:

```
<form>
<input type="submit" value="click me" />
</form>
```

and maybe an explicit ajax post in the onclick event? will try this one later.. but i guess i am missing something here. can i send posts with an anchor, image or a simple button without a form?

thanx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP communicates primarily using different verbs, `GET` and `POST` being the most common.

The reason why `runat="server"` works in Web Forms is because that ASP.NET wraps a whole majority of the page in a `<form>` tag, and the default browser action for a `<form>` submission is via `POST`. Well, at least that's the gist of it.

If you want to perform an `HTTP POST`, you'll either have to use a `<form>` natively, or set up an AJAX call to do it, and make it so that it shoots the request back up as an `HTTP POST` as you mentioned.

Comment: inside a `<form>`, is there a simple way to do posts f.e. in a `<select>` without ajax?

Comment: Short of actually submitting the `<form>`? I don't think so. I'm curious though why you're so adverse to using AJAX. :p

Comment: i'm not, im just curious. AJAX seems intricate, i cannot be the only one who expected something like `<form defaultForInput="mySubmitId"><select id="mySubmitId">...</select></form>`. but i guess i am